# how to split amount column into number of months based on given Days in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with my `SQL Server`, my columns have to calculate remaining_days based on the difference between todays_date and end_date. Then I want it to calculate how many months that is, then the amount_monthly should calculate how much money I have each month.

Example:

[image: table]

I made this in excel just to give you an idea on how I want it.

Comment: write an example of your result

Comment: PO Balance Amount Today's Date New End date Remaining days
   
 $14,117.64          10/29/2015   1/4/2016    67

Comment: When people ask for examples, they're usually trying to prompt you to [edit] your question - where you can use formatting tools. Trying to show tabular data in comments is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so here's my Balance table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Balance] (
[Id]             INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Balance]        DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[Today_Date]     AS              (CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126))),
[Date_end]       DATE            NOT NULL,
[Remaining_Days] AS              (datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end])),
[In_Months]      AS              (datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end])/(30)),
[Amount_Monthly] AS              (CONVERT([decimal](18,2),case when datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end])/(30)=(0) then NULL else [Balance]/(datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end])/(30)) end)),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

Here is the Months table that we use to insert some data into:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Months] (
[Id]              INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Month]           VARCHAR (15)    NULL,
[Balance_monthly] DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And here is the trigger which is on the Balance table, this will calculate it for you depending on how many months there is.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Balance_monthly]
ON [dbo].[Balance]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Months
    SET Months.Balance_monthly = 
    ((Balance.In_Months + 12 - Months.Id) / 12) * Amount_Monthly          
    FROM Balance
    CROSS JOIN Months;

END
```

Comment: 2 decimals is fine, but I need Amount to be split across Months like 2015-11 2015-12 2016-01 2016-02

Comment: Amount to be split across Months like 2015-11 2015-12  2016-01 2016-02  in columns

Comment: I think we have to use EOMONTH to get next month of current date but its not supporting in SQL server 2008

Comment: that's fine my main requirement is need to split amount across next months from today date

Comment: If Remaining days is 60 amount has to split across months from Today's date like 2015-12, 2016-01

Comment: are you able to split it?

Comment: My requirement is to get in every month

Comment: how to split amount into every month in separate table

Comment: can anyone help me on this